# Simplifying $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}(6-2\sqrt{5})^{1/4}}$

Tags: calculus, radicals

I have the radical
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}(6-2\sqrt{5})^{1/4}}$$ for exam preparation (middle school):

[image]

I need to simplify it in natural numbers.

My attempt is:

We know the rule:
$(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$

Let's $a^2+b^2=6$, then $2ab=2\sqrt5$ and $ab=\sqrt5$, suppose that $b=1$, then $a=\sqrt5$.

$(6-2\sqrt{5})^{1/4}=(1^2-2\cdot1\cdot\sqrt{5}+(\sqrt{5})^2)^{1/4}=(\sqrt{5}-1)^{1/2}$

After first step:

$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}$

*Question*. What is a possible next step?
Or possible error/typo in the task. The answer is 2.

Comment: I don't unerstand $(6-2\sqrt{5})^{1/4}=(1^2-2\cdot1\cdot\sqrt{5}+(\sqrt{5})^2)$. How do you geet this, can you explain?

Comment: @miracle173, i have fixed the typo and added details

Comment: $(6-2\sqrt(5))^{1/4}=1.111785940502842$ but $(1-\sqrt(5))^2=1.527864045000421$

Comment: The resulting value is 1.86709.....,I don't think it can simplified in natural numbers

Comment: Also,it should be $\sqrt5 -1$. in the sq.root

Comment: May be error/typo in the task? The answer is 2.

Comment: @Nick The expression above most certainly does not equal $2$. Could you provide information about the source of the question?

Comment: @learning123, source is a school test for exam preparation.

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be $\sqrt{(1+\sqrt5)\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5}}$. That does evaluate to $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson), the expression is likely supposed to be
$$\sqrt{(1+\sqrt5)\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5}}$$
$$= \sqrt{(\sqrt{5} + 1)(\sqrt{5} - 1)}$$
$$= \sqrt{5 - 1}$$
$$= 2$$

Remark: My intention to answer this question is less to *answer* the question (which I believe the OP is completely capable of doing themselves) and more to remove this question from the unanswered section.